# Liferay ext plugin is not (fully) working on CentOS but it does on Windows, why?

Tags: java-8, centos, liferay, wildfly

I've already posted my problem in the Liferay's forum, [this is the link](https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/84892803) in case that you want to post an answer also there.

My ext-plugin is working partially on dev environment (CentOS) but in my laptop (Windows 7) there is no problem, I mean partially because with the project I'm modifying two classes and I see changes reflected of one but not of the other.

The classes belong to different packages:

```
bad:
/projectname-ext-util-taglib/src/main/java/com/liferay/taglib/ui/BreadcrumbTag.java

good:
/projectname-ext-impl/src/main/java/com/liferay/portal/repository/cmis/CMISAtomPubRepository.java
```

Other relevant information:

- Liferay 6.2 GA6
- Oracle JDK 8
- WildFly 10.1.0
- CentOS 7

I compared files from application servers and I didn't find significant differences.

Could it be a platform problem? what do you suggest me to try?

Thank you.

Comment: So after you deploy the updated EXT with the changed 2 files on both environments,it works on only one?Have u checked the jars in ext on both environments for reflected changes?

Comment: Yes @ShivamAggarwal the problem occurs only in CentOS. I unzipped all the jars and compared it again, all the binary and text files are identical. Also I searched in database and didn't find anything. In addition to the operating system, another difference between the environments is the update of the JDK 8, I'm going to put the same and test again